# Sometimes keyboard & touchpad work... sometimes not

Tags: 10.10, hardware, keyboard, touchpad, synaptics

When I first ran Ubuntu from CD on this Dell Inspiron 2650, it worked for about ten to fifteen minutes, then it hung (I was probably trying to do too much at once from a Live CD). The next time, my mouse and keyboard didn't work. I rebooted three times and finally got them working. I then installed Ubuntu alongside Windows XP.

After installing, selecting the OS in GRUB worked, but my touchpad and keyboard were again not working. I rebooted, and they worked. (I fortunately had a USB mouse with which to reboot.)

Booting Ubuntu and then rebooting to enable my keyboard and touchpad has become a routine ever since. Often several reboots are required; at one point I had to reboot over a dozen times in a row before getting a session where everything worked properly. (My installation has been in place for about <del>three days</del> a week now.) I've looked around for a device manager equivalent to no avail.

Sometimes the hardware is properly detected, and sometimes it's not. Once or twice I've had the keyboard detected properly but the touchpad not.

Plugging in my wireless card also sometimes requires a plug, unplug, and plug again to get it working.

So is there some solution? I'm without an Internet connection at home, and this "laptop" is really a wall wart on my desk, so suggestions for packages may take a while to test.

#### Xorg logs

I captured <del>two</del> <del>three</del> four sample Xorg logs: one from a startup where the devices worked; one from when they didn't; one from a session where Ubuntu thought my touchpad was a normal mouse; and one from a session where my keyboard worked but the touchpad didn't.

[See this gist](https://gist.github.com/736863). Updated 2010-12-15 01:50 UTC with `Xorg.0.log.keyboardonly` file illustrating the case where the keyboard worked but not the touchpad. Updated 2011-01-11 04:10 UTC with `Xorg.0.log.touchpadregmouse` to illustrate a case where the touchpad was detected as a regular mouse (no "Touchpad" tab in mouse prefs).

Comment: This question has not information added in it for a very long time and probably describes a bug in old package versions. I have flagged it to a moderator so it can be closed. If you think that this is still a valid question and that you are still suffering for this issue you can always flag it so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a friends Laptop Dell inspiron 2650.  Once I get the keyboard and touchpad to work, I set up the power button to hibernate and to hibernate when the lid is closed.  Then, I never completely shut it down.  It hibernates when i press power button and when close lid.  I only have one logon because when I had two and I would log out of one to log into the other, it would stop working.  This is a great workaround until I figure it out.  So far so good.  I've even taken the battery out and as long as it is hybernating, it works when I wake it back up.

Comment: That's a great workaround, and I'll gladly give you an upvote for it. It won't solve my problem because I'm also having trouble with hibernation and sleep mode (the machine resumes to an unusable state, full of graphics glitches), but it really deserves a vote. Thanks, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! :-)