# Touchpad on Dell laptop unresponsive

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, mouse, touchpad

After running ubuntu 10.10 on a dell latitude D830 flawlessly for a couple weeks, I booted it up to find the mouse completely unresponsive, a few restarts later it started working again, any ideas?

```
tia@DELL-ORA:~$ xinput list ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)] ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer              id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: I'm going to favorite this question, as I think it's potentially related to my input-device issues. http://askubuntu.com/questions/16813/sometimes-keyboard-touchpad-work-sometimes-not

Comment: This question has not information added in it for a very long time and probably describes a bug in old package versions. I have flagged it to a moderator so it can be closed. If you think that this is still a valid question and that you are still suffering for this issue you can always flag it so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Many laptops/notebooks have a magic key-combination to enable/disable the touchpad (useful when using a trackpoint or external tablet/mouse);  does toggling that combination help.  I'm not sure what the combination on your Dell is going to be—on this ThinkPad it is <kbd>Fn+F8</kbd>.

Comment: Most Dells do not have a magic key for this, 99% of the time Dell Latitude laptops have the touchpads active all the time.