# USB 2.0 and NIC not recognized on a ASUS M5A97 Pro

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, usb, networking, asus

I have much trouble with Ubuntu 11.10. I have a quite new system with an ASUS M5A97, and neither NIC nor USB 2.0 are working. The first problem could be solved by using a vendor driver, but the latter still exists. Mouse (Logitech MX900) and keyboard (Logitech Illuminated KB) are not recognized. I have older devices with I have kept for emergencies  plugged to USB 3.0 or PS/2 which are then regognized and working.

This chipset problem almost only exists in Ubuntu, live CDs based on other distrubutions (System Rescue CD, Parted Magic) work just fine. There is a guy reporting to have the same problem with Archlinux, but it hasn't been solved to date:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=125735

Is there any chance that this issue (the board is out for sale since january) will be solved one day? Has anyone an idea what to do to get the onboard USB running? Apart from switching to another distribution, of course.

Comment: The only way to have it solved is to file a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

A firmware update to 0810 Beta (2011/10/11) via EZ Flash seems to solve the problem. The keyboard is running, the mouse still not, but this seems to be a bluetooth issue:

[Keyboard/Mouse not recognised during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2258/keyboard-mouse-not-recognised-during-installation)

Thanks so far.

Comment: tried the bios update, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to download the 8068 driver and use these instructions to install it.

http://www.twm-kd.com/linux/realtek-rtl81688111e-and-ubuntu-linux/

the bad news, is that this doesn't seem to work on 3.2 kernels.

but my network is working now, since i'm running oneric. (bios update did nothing for me)